# SQLite3 prepared statements for metro app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012) and I downloaded SQLite 3.7.13 from [link](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and successfully integrated with my app using [this](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) procedure, By using below code I can create table and insert data

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.db");
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
            {
                db.CreateTable<Test>();
                db.RunInTransaction(() =>
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                            db.Insert(new Test() { id = i,dept = "CS", Firstname = "First" + i.ToString(), Lastname = "Last" + i.ToString() });
                        }
                    });                
            }
```

Where Test my inner class

```
class Test
    {
        [AutoIncrement,PrimaryKey]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string dept { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1}", Lastname, Firstname);
        }
    }
```

By using below code i can retrieve all the records in Test table

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.db");
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
            {   
                var data = db.Table<Test>();                    
            }
```

So my question is how can we give prepared statements in SQLLite?
For example: if i want to find the count of records of dept "CS" in my table, and
             what if i want the records of only dept "CS" from my table
Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Linq statements:

- *Count*

  var count = db.Table<Test>().Count();
- *Filtering*

  var data = db.Table<Test>().Where(test => test.dept == "CS");

Comment: Thanks dbaseman, Can you tell me one thing, how can i write one more condition in where, 
For example: select count(*) from table_name where column1 = 'Y' and column2 = 'N';

Comment: @RajkumarMandera you can chain the requests, like *db.Table<Test>().Where(test => test.col1=="Y" && test.col2=="N").Count()*.

Comment: Thankyou dbaseman, Can you do me a favor, do you have any link where I can learn how to create this Linq statements, because i need to learn these things and how to use them.

Comment: @RajkumarMandera I looked around a bit, but couldn't find a concise intro/tutorial.  I'd suggest just googling or searching here on SO, there's tons of info out there.